# How to pass a list as an argument when using restful api and flask

Tags: python, flask-restful

I am trying to create an API to parse a list as an argument however I am not sure how to go forward I had experienced a couple of errors, I am pretty sure you pros may spot an error in this.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('list', type=list)

@app.route('/')
def get():

    ABC = parser.parse_args()
    print(*ABC)
    return ABC

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is my API request

```
import requests

BASE = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/"

response = requests.get(BASE, [1,2,3])

print (response)
```

Thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: did you try using ```post``` ? I think ```post``` method is appropriate in this situation

Comment: something like this ```requests.post(url, data = "your data")```

Comment: nope didn't work, I get this error, TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object

Comment: did you convert your data to string? if not the problem could be that

Comment: Yeah did not work :( I could just take each value in the array as a param and use int instead of list that would work but I wanted to try to use a list

Comment: so you can get the data in your ```get``` function ?

Comment: yep only if its a string int boolean,...

Comment: create your data like this ```data = json.dumps({"data":[1,2,3,4]})``` and then give data to that post function

Comment: I get <Response [405]> status error

Comment: add this to your function ```@app.route('/',methods = ['POST'])```

Comment: still doesn't work hmm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I changed your code a little but it is working now

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('list', type=list)

@app.route('/',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def get():
    ABC = parser.parse_args()
    print(request.data)
    return jsonify("whatever")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

now send your data like this :

```py
import json
import requests

requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/", data=json.dumps({"name": ["foo", "poo", "koo"]}))
```

now you've got the data.

Comment: thanks where the jsonify("whatever") is supposed to be seen ? on browser or terminal or ... ? I don't see it on terminal but I see the result of print(requrest.data)

Comment: @Areza it is refering to the endpoint which in this case is a `get` method pointing to this address `/` (`home` so to speak). But have this in mind that I just wrote "whatever" you can put your dictionary (containing data) in this method `jsonify` to get data in a json manner in the address mentioned in `@app.route`